# Updating single record in PHP While Loop

Tags: php, sql

Sooo I've been working on a site for a friend of my dads so he can keep his business in check etc. I've been using the While Loop to print out a table of the 'Tasks' that can be inputted in to the site, however when I go to change the status of the task it's not doing so?

I'm sure that is the way I'm getting the ID for locating the record that needs to be updated, but I think I'm on the correct lines. So firstly, is there anything obvious other than my shoddy coding? Secondly, this there any better way of getting the ID or the reasoning for the lack of updating? Much Obliged! 
HTML - The page

```
<table class="tasktable">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 100px ">Job Number (ID)</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 100px">VRM</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 175px;">Date Arrived</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Work</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width:200px;">Customer</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 250px;">Task Progress</th>
            </tr>
            <?php

            include 'Login-System/db.php';

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM outstanding WHERE taskprogress = "New" OR taskprogress = "In Progress" ORDER by id ASC';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


            if($result):
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
                    while($tasks = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><h4 name="jobnumberid"><?php echo $tasks['id'];?></h4></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><h4><?php echo $tasks['VRM'];?></h4></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><h4><?php echo $tasks['datearrived'];?></h4></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><h4><?php echo $tasks['work'];?></h4></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><h4><?php echo $tasks['customer'];?></h4></td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="SQL/taskchange.php" role="form" method="post" id="taskchange">
                                    <select name="taskchanger" id="taskchanger" style="margin-top:6px; 
    width: 150px; float:left" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="#"><?php echo $tasks['taskprogress'];?></option>
                                        <?php

                                        if ($tasks['taskprogress']== "New") {
                                            echo '<option value="In Progress" class="form-control">In Progress</option>
                                            <option value="Complete" class="form-control">Complete</option>';
                                        } else { if ($tasks['taskprogress']== "In Progress") {
                                            echo '<option value="New" class="form-control">New</option>
                                            <option value="Complete" class="form-control">Complete</option>';
                                            } else {
                                            echo '<option value="New" class="form-control">New</option>
                                                option value="In Progress" class="form-control">In Progress</option>';
                                            }
                                        }

                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    <button name="save" id="save" class="form-control" style="width: 75px; float:right;margin-top: 6px">Save</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            endif;
            ?>
        </table>
```

PHP - Bit that inserts into the DB

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['save'])){

include '../Login-System/db.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['jobnumberid']);
$newtask = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['taskchanger']);

$sql = "UPDATE outstanding SET taskprogress = '$newtask' WHERE id = '$id'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../outstanding.php?updated");
exit();
} else {
header("Location: ../outstanding.php?whoops");
exit();
}
```

Comment: You don't have any form elements within your `<form>` with `name="jobnumberid"`. That's pretty much all you're missing. Try adding `<input type="hidden" name="jobnumberid" value="<?= $tasks['id'] ?>">` and make sure it's a child of your `<form>` tag

Comment: Some advice... the check for `num_rows` is completely redundant; the `while` loop will run zero or more times. Also, read up on how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php); concatenating values into query string is never safe, even with `real_escape_string`

Comment: Motherfu**** I knew it'll be something small that I had over looked! Thanks Phil, it works and I have saved that for some light reading.

Comment: It always is ;). FYI, this all looks pretty good, nothing obviously _"shoddy"_

Comment: Also, your browser's _Network_ console is very handy for debugging client / server HTTP data. In it, you would see that there was no `jobnumberid` being sent in the POST request

Comment: Thank god! Wonderful this will also solve the other issues I have been putting off :D Yeah I use it every now again but didn't know that so thanks Chief! *Tips hat*